# ruby on rails: why isn't there a migration for every new model association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, database-schema

My understanding is that relationships between tables are implemented through foreign keys. But when you add an association between models (belongs_to, etc), there is no change in the database schema. Why is that? How does rails actually know there is an association or relationship?

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is that belongs_to, has_one, has_many only works if the appropriate keys are already in the database.

The keys are usually `<model>_id`.

So a belongs_to relationship between post and blog requires you to have a blog_id in the posts table that you had to create using a relation.

Same goes for a has_many between blog and post.

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

Requires a migration that creates the `blog_id` foreign key in the posts table.

Answer (score 0):

Rails will recognize the associations among the all tables by mentioning those relations in the models only, but not only with the foreign keys. If you don't follow the naming convention for the foreign keys, rails will loose finding the relation between the tables even you mention the relation in the models. Then you have to tell the foreign_key, and class names explicitly.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments
end
```

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :article
end
```

In the comments table, you have to maintain the `article_id` along with its own fields.
Then rails will automatically assumes that `article_id` as `foriegn_key`. 
If you write something else(Ex: `art_id`) rather `article_id` you have to tell as:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :article, :class_name=>"Article", :foreign_key=>:art_id
end
```

Comment: If you write something else(Ex: `art_id`) rather `article_id` you have to tell as: `belongs_to :article, :class_name=>Article, :foreign_key=>:art_id`